# How do I set the build output platform x86_64 in a Skaffold configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Since I'm developing on an M1 mac, my Docker builds will build ARM. I want to build x86_64 images which I know I can build with the `--platform` flag but I want to do that with my Skaffold configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @p10l putting me on the right track, I was able to figure it out. Skaffold can't set the platform using the Docker Engine API, so we need to pass `--platform=linux/x86_64` to the command line by setting `useDockerCLI` to `true` and adding `cliFlags` to our Docker configuration.

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta26
kind: Config
build:
  # ... other unrelated config ...
  artifacts:
    - image: my-image
      context: ./
      docker:
        cliFlags:
          - --platform=linux/x86_64 
  local:
    useDockerCLI: true # the only way to set platform is with cliFlags so we need to enable the Docker CLI
```

Comment: Works like a charm for me aswell on a m1 mac - without complicated configs etc. Works also with helm involved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whoever is coming here from google and confront this problem, skaffold almost finished developing [multi-arch support](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/7082) but as the version of v1.39.1, you can use

`skaffold run --platform linux/amd64`

or simply to configure it in [skaffold.yaml file](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/#build-artifacts-platforms)

Answer (score 0):

Skaffold has [`buildCommand`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/#build-artifacts-custom-buildCommand) field to which you can pass a custom script.
So, for example

```yaml
...
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: "foo"
    context: .
    custom:
      buildCommand: ./build.sh
...
```

*build.sh*

```sh
docker buildx build \
  --platform linux/amd64
  ... # any other flags
```

---

**Disclaimer**: Everything below is a speculation. I'm currently unable to test this, but I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

There is also [`build.artifacts.docker`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/#build-artifacts-docker) field (currently in beta). It may be possible to use this field to pass arguments to Docker build.

```yaml
...
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: "foo"
    context: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: <Dockerfile relative to workspace>
      target: <Dockerfile target name to build>
      buildArgs:
        platform: linux/amd64
  local:
    useDockerCLI: true #this is needed to use docker build CLI rather than Docker Engine API
```

It may also be required to set `buildx` as a default builder for Docker. This can be achieved with

```text
docker buildx install
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I haven't had time to try it yet but I will do it within in the next couple of days